# Problems understanding NsdChat sample app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, instance

I'm not sure I understand how this android sample works (NsdChat found in developer.android Tutorials).

My first idea was to run 2 istances of the App (with 2 instances of Eclipse on the same machine) and try make them communicate but, it doesn't seem to work: I can't figure out if registration and discovery buttons works and while trying to send a message from 1 to another the destination App show nothing and the Eclipse console of BOTH istances show "Client sent message:test", why?

Maybe I haven't completely understood how the example works. Can someone explain to me how to execute and understand this sample?

Comment: Any luck in finding a solution to this? I am trying to test the sample app. I start the service on one device, "Register", and then "Discover" and "Connect" on the other device. In my case the second device discovers the service but when it tries to connect the connection is refused.

Answer (score 3):

your first idea correct. it's run two instance of the app on two phones.
one register the service.
the other one discover and connect. then you can talk. 
the samples(NsdHelper.java) have bugs, you need fix it.

Or you just change SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp." to "_ipp._tcp.", NsdChat can be an printer, you even can print on it from Mac.